# Pyqt5 timeline skips frames on pressing play button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, timeline, frames

I am trying to use Pyqt timeline for frame based approach. I want it to run every frame, no matter what, even if i add time.sleep for 1 second. It starts skipping frames if framechangeup function/method has lots of things to do.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import time


class mainWin(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWin, self).__init__(parent)

        ffr = 1
        lfr = 1440

        self.frameRate = 25

        self.timeLength = ((lfr + 1 - ffr) / self.frameRate) * 1000

        print(self.timeLength)

        self.tl = QTimeLine(self.timeLength)
        self.tl.setFrameRange(ffr, lfr)
        self.tl.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Linear)
        self.tl.loopCount = 0

        self.tl.frameChanged.connect(self.framechangeup)

        self.center()
        self.winWidgets()

    def framechangeup(self):
        self.tl.setPaused(True)
        print(self.tl.currentFrame())
        self.cfr = self.tl.currentFrame()
        self.curF.setText(str(self.cfr))

        time.sleep(0.3)
        self.tl.resume()

    def winWidgets(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        # hbox.addStretch(1)

        playBut = QPushButton("play", self)
        playBut.setToolTip("This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget")
        playBut.resize(playBut.sizeHint())

        stpBut = QPushButton("stop", self)
        stpBut.setToolTip("This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget")
        stpBut.resize(stpBut.sizeHint())

        hbox.addWidget(playBut)
        playBut.clicked.connect(self.playbut)

        hbox.addWidget(stpBut)
        stpBut.clicked.connect(self.stpbut)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        cfr = 1

        editsbox = QHBoxLayout()

        cfLable = QLabel("cur Frame")

        self.curF = QLineEdit()
        self.curF.setReadOnly(True)
        self.curF.setText(str(cfr))

        lastF = QLineEdit()

        editsbox.addWidget(cfLable)
        editsbox.addWidget(self.curF)

        vbox.addLayout(editsbox)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def playbut(self):
        self.tl.start()

    def stpbut(self):
        self.tl.stop()
        print("stp")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    exe = mainWin()
    exe.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Even if i try to do it without Qtimeline I need to use threading it seems.

Comment: I don't understand your question, explain yourself better

Comment: @ when framechangeup() runs (upon pressing play button), it should print all numbers incrementing from 1 to infinity till we press stop button. But it skips nubers, randomly. Try and press play... stop... several times.. and see printed numbers in terminal.. there are not all numbers in output.. Hope I made it more clear now...

Comment: Qt animations always respect the expected duration, so it might skip values (and then, frames) if there's not enough time to process everything. If you want to always show all frames, you should use a QTimer instead and set it based on the preferred frame rate, which will obviously result in a (possibly slightly) slower rate due to event processing. Also, you should not use `time.sleep` to do this.

Comment: Thank you musucamante. Ill Try QTimer. And time.sleep was just a placeholder of kind... there actual process will happen which will take certain time... Thank you very much for suggestions... Ill try this one...

Comment: Also QTimer doesn't seem to have functionality like play, pause, frames, frame update etc.

Comment: It's up to you to implement that; for example, you could make a subclass based on QTimer and keep an internal variable for the frames, then emit a custom signal each timeout with the changed frame.